# the combination of association rules results in one group

Tags: algorithm, frequency, rules, apriori

I have groups of the result sorted by frequency of distinct association rules , I want to create a general association rules that combines everything in those groups in one group, like i want to take the result of an apriori algorithm from three research and i want to collect them in one research,  Is this method correct?

I have multiple sets of association rules generated from different datasets or research studies and you aim to consolidate them into a single set of rules for analysis or comparison

Combining association rules from different groups may not always yield meaningful or accurate results.